# Anaconda : IPython not running

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, anaconda

I am a newbie to python and needed to set up IPython for some project-work. I followed the Anaconda Installation Directions . Currently I am having a lot of problem in running IPython :

> - First I installed Anaconda in my home directory : `\home\pranav`
> - Next I ran the command `conda` just to check if the installation was correct - it turned out to be prefectly fine
> - When I type in `ipython` OR `ipython notebook` , I get the following error :
>
> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
>       from IPython import start_ipython
>   ImportError: No module named IPython`

Can someone help me out ? Changing / Adding the PATH Variable is not working as suggested elsewhere on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What was required was just a clean install of IPython :

> - `pip install ipython`
> - `pip install 'ipython[all]'`

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Ipython is probably not installed. Try running the below commands

```
conda update conda
conda update ipython ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole
```

Comment: sorry @pranav but this is the correct approach.  You may have needed to `conda install ipython-notebook` rather than `conda update`.  It looks like your /usr/local/bin/ipython was in the way of the path set by the anaconda distribution.  Creating an environment would have cleared that up (make sure to `conda install ipython` into the environment.

Answer (score 0):

It was installed in my `base` environment but not in an newly created Python 3.6 environment so I had to activate it and then run `conda install -c anaconda ipython`  from here: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/ipython